# WEbdriver with Touch events

Tags: touch, webdriver

I wanted to use touch/tap events in Selenium WebDriver using Java code for iOS iPad or Android tablets.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is AndroidDriver that you can use to test a web application / web site on an Android device.
Link: [Android WebDriver](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AndroidDriver)
For iOS, there is WebDriver for iPhone
Link: [iPhone WebDriver](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/IPhoneDriver)
Also, do check this:
 [WebDriver for Mobile Browsers](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverForMobileBrowsers)

Since, the drivers are for automation testing of web views/pages they don't have out of the box touch/tap events like native app automation frameworks. 
You should try to use [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) API to perform touch/tap events on web-pages. Use [JavascriptExecutor](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html) of selenium webdriver and execute jquery using the executor.
Check this: [jQuery Mobile Tap](http://api.jquerymobile.com/tap/)

Comment: @user2000759: I would suggest you to study some basics of jQuery and javascript to understand how it works. And yes, you can use jQuery with Java WebDriver. Once you are done understanding jQuery and Javascript, check these links:
[link1](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/webdriver/b6H2R1Gt5qc)
[link2](http://teammentordevelopment.wordpress.com/2013/02/04/using-webdriver-and-the-power-of-jquery-to-interact-with-html-elements/)
[link3](http://www.code-thrill.com/2012/04/integrating-jquery-with-selenium.html)

Comment: Also, if my answer has proved helpful to you, please consider accepting it by clicking on the left check mark next to my answer.

Comment: Thank you Abhijeet: I tried today.
<Code>
String javascriptToExecute = "window.jQuery(//document.elementFromPoint("
    + getElementXPosition(elementToTap) + ","
    + getElementYPosition(elementToTap) + "))" + SINGLETAP;   
  
  executeJavascript(javascriptToExecute); <Code>

But webdriver could not found the element and not error is throwing (only timeout error). Can you check this.

Answer (score 1):

For Android TouchEvents are available.

Here is a code snippet that moves a slider on the Google Search Results page for weather in San Francisco. I cannot guarantee you will get the same results for the search query that's what Google decides :) however I hope this example is enough to get you started.

This example uses the Junit 4 test runner, you can tweak the code to run in Junit 3 and other test runners, etc.

```
package org.example.androidtests;

import static org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Dimension;
import org.openqa.selenium.Point;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.android.AndroidDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.touch.TouchActions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Wait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class AndroidDemoTest {

    @Test 
    public void test() throws InterruptedException {
        AndroidDriver driver = new AndroidDriver();
        Wait<WebDriver> wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);

        driver.get("http://www.google.co.uk");
        WebElement q = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
        q.sendKeys("weather in san francisco");
        q.submit();

        WebElement slider = wait.until(visibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("wob_shi")));

        Point location = slider.getLocation();
        Dimension size = slider.getSize();

        // Find the center of this element where we we start the 'touch'
        int x = location.getX() + (size.getWidth() / 2);
        int y = location.getY() + (size.getHeight() / 2);

        new TouchActions(driver).down(x, y).move(150, 0).perform();

    }
}
```

Note: if you want to have tests that work on both iOS and Android platforms, you will need another approach, perhaps using JQuery Mobile as suggested in another answer to your question. The following article also describes how to use JQuery to simulate touch events for iOS http://seleniumgrid.wordpress.com/2012/06/01/how-to-simulate-touch-actions-using-webdriver-in-iphone-or-ipad/

Comment: I followed same as mentioned in the above link but my iphone driver could not click on the Link.

Comment: same code (with minor modifications) working in Android device.

Comment: What happened instead when you use the iphone driver? Perhaps you could add some details to your question, including a sample of your code?

Comment: driver = new IPhoneDriver("http://10.160.144.22:3001/wd/hub");
driver.get("URL")
driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendkeys("admin");
driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("password");
WebElement Element = driver.finelement(By.name("Submit"));
Action Tchact = new TouchActins(driver).singleTap(Element).build();
Tchact.perform();

In the Above code: I could execute the same with Android device but for iPhone device: I am getting error message <iPhone driver can not cast to HasTouchScreen>.

Comment: Does that replace the `AndroidDriver driver = new AndroidDriver();` line of code?  Can you also paste any error message here somewhere to help diagnose the problem?

Comment: Exact error message is 
<java.lang.classCastException: org.openqa.selenium.iphone.IPhoneDriver cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.HasTouchScreen>

Comment: OK, let's check my understanding of what you're currently trying: you're trying to run the example code I provided for the AndroidDriver however you have changed the driver to use the iPhoneDriver? If so, that will not work for you. The iPhoneDriver does not support Touch Actions - this was why both Abhijeet and I mentioned the JQuery alternative.

Comment: I tried JQuery also. but no luck.
String javascriptToExecute = "return window.jQuery(//document.elementFromPoint("+ 500 + "," + 200 + "))" + SINGLETAP;                        

Where singletap: private static String SINGLETAP = ".trigger(‘tap’);";

                        System.out.println("javascriptToExecute:"+javascriptToExecute);

Comment: 500 and 200 are the element X position and Y position.

Comment: This may seem a silly question, however your code seems to be commented out by `//`. Is this correct? I quickly looked at JQuery syntax (I don't have much experience using it) in case this was by design, however it doesn't seem to be. What happens if you remove the `//` characters?

Comment: sorry.. typo error.// are not there. please read the code by removing //.

Comment: Please can you create a new question on StackOverflow with your complete code included (the contents of the entire Java file), then add a link here. That should make your question easier to answer.