# Can bots simulate onTouch events?

Tags: javascript, mobile, server-side, spam-prevention

Question. To protect a mobile website from being victim to SPAM/Bots and without the need of implementing unfriendly UX CAPTCHA. Hypothetically if we were to disable (from the server side) onClick events but allow onTouch events. Are bots able to replicate the onTouch function? Ensuring that only human hands are able to use the site?

Answer (score 1):

Considering the UI programming models/APIs that browsers expose for the developers (viz. hackers/spammers), it's not hard to emulate click/touch events on your web application. One point to keep in mind is that like onClick event handlers, onTouchStart, end, drag all can be replicated using JavaScript callbacks.

In other words, the touch/click APIs are analogous to each other from a language perspective. It's just the browser implementation that makes them different.

Answer (score 0):

Yes they can. One way of doing it is using Selenium to drive an Android phone/tablet. I've never done it myself but this answer illustrates how it could be done: [WEbdriver with Touch events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15791962/webdriver-with-touch-events#answer-15829157)

Basically, the Selenium Android driver exposes TouchActions that can be used to trigger touch events:

```
new TouchActions(driver).down(x, y).move(150, 0).perform();
```

You'd need an Android device to do this. Though you could probably also do it with the Android emulator that comes with the Android SDK.